# uthash add malloc strcpy printf prints garbage values

Tags: c, struct, malloc, printf

I am using uthash (http://uthash.sourceforge.net/userguide.html) to use a Hash Table implementation in my C Program.

I am trying to printf the data that is being added to the hash table before and after the addition and I get garbage values when I print it after the malloc. Please see the following code.

```
void add_user(int user_id, char *name)
{
    printf("User ID : %d Name : %s, user_id,name); // Prints fine !!
    struct my_struct *s;
    s = malloc(sizeof(struct my_struct));
    s->id = user_id;
    strcpy(s->name, name);

    printf("User ID : %d Name : %s, s->user_id,s->name); // Prints User ID fine, but for Name, only half of it is printed right, rest is Garbage !!

    HASH_ADD_INT( users, id, s );
}
```

If I do the following :

```
void add_user(int user_id, char *name)
{
    printf("User ID : %d Name : %s, user_id,name); // Prints fine !!

    struct my_struct *s;
    s = malloc(sizeof(struct my_struct));

    printf("User ID : %d Name : %s, user_id,name); // Printing same as previous printf then I get Garbage values printed for Name

}
```

BUT if I comment out malloc as well, then both printf statements print correctly.

HELP !!!

Comment: Hard to guess without seeing what your `my_struct` looks like. Maybe you are using a pointer to store the `name` in your struct? In that case you do need to allocate (separately!) space for it before you try to copy a string into it. Otherwise you are polluting your memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gosh, I posted the question and in the next 2 mins I figured it out.

YePHlcK, you are kinda right. However, the thing which didn't have the memory allocated here was *name which was coming in.

The function was called like this :

```
add_user(r.user_id, r.name); // r itself is a struct where name was a pointer and not a char array.
```

Changing name to a char array and then initializing it by using strcpy(r.name,"blah"); and then calling add solved the problem. Because strcpy would take care of allocation of memory ?!?!! Correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When `r.name` is a pointer, then you have to manually allocate memory for it, `strcpy` doesn't care for this. When it is a char array, then the memory is already there. Additionally, if the pointer wasn't initialized, then it may point to any (invalid) memory address. `strcpy` doesn't care for this, either, so you'd try to copy the string to this address, whereever it is.

The same may apply for your struct, as YePhIcK commented. When `s.name` is a pointer, then you need to allocate the memory for it:

```
s = malloc(sizeof(struct my_struct));
s->id = user_id;
s->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
strcpy(s->name, name);
```

If you allocate a fixed amount or if it is a char array, then do **not** use `strcpy` for this, because it doesn't care for the destination size, too. You will end with a potential buffer overflow when the given `name` is longer than the available space. This is a whole discussion of its own, just search for strcpy here.

Last, `malloc` may fail and returns `NULL` then. You should always check for this and take appropriate action. This is another discussion of its own.